# Pass datas between methods and forms (List<t>)

Tags: c#, list, forms, methods, interface

i have two form, a sort of ***console*** where you can add Customers and Products, and a ***shop*** where you can check which customers are in the list, which products, and you can also bind them in an unique object (a cart) via listboxes. My problem is that forms can't share datas at the moment so i was wondering how.

I know i could use databases, but thats just practice, so i would like to know.

The ***console*** has a button to go back to ***shop***:

```
        private void tornaAlloShopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shop Login = new Shop();
        Login.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

The code will be long, since those list are stored in lists, which are in my interface implementation, this is the part of it which has lists:

```
    public class DBMemoryManager : DBManager
{

    //Arrays

    List<ClienteModel> MemoryClienti = new List<ClienteModel>();
    List<ProdottoModel> MemoryProdotti = new List<ProdottoModel>();
    List<CarrelloModel> MemoryCarrello = new List<CarrelloModel>();
```

This is the initial part of the **console** form.cs:

```
 public partial class ConsoleAnagrafica : Form
{
    //Istanziazione [0]

    DBMemoryManager dbMemoryManager = null;

    public ConsoleAnagrafica()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Istanziazione [1]

        dbMemoryManager = new DBMemoryManager();
    }
```

This, instead, is the **shop** starting code:

```
public partial class Shop : Form
{
    //Istanziazione [0]

    DBMemoryManager dbMemoryManager = null;

    public Shop()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Shop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Istanziazione [1]

        dbMemoryManager = new DBMemoryManager();
    }
```

In this way i can recall all the methods from my `interface`:

```
public interface DBManager
{
    //Carrello

    void CreateCarrello (CarrelloModel model);
    List<CarrelloModel> ReadAllCarrello (CarrelloModel model);

    //Cliente
    
    bool CreateCliente(ClienteModel model);
    void UpdateCliente(ClienteModel model);
    void DeleteCliente(ClienteModel model);
    List<ClienteModel> ReadAllCliente(ClienteModel model);
    
    
    //Ordine

    bool CreateProdotto(ProdottoModel model);
    void UpdateProdotto(ProdottoModel model);
    void DeleteProdotto(ProdottoModel model);
    List<ProdottoModel> ReadAllProdotto(ProdottoModel model);
}
```

The code i use to update the **shop's** listboxes is:

```
private void aggiornaListeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarrelloModel carrelloModel = null;
        carrelloModel = new CarrelloModel();
        var memoryCarrello = dbMemoryManager.ReadAllCarrello(carrelloModel);
        carrelloListBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (CarrelloModel model in memoryCarrello)
        {
            carrelloListBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", carrelloModel.RiferimentoIDCliente, carrelloModel.RiferimentoIDProdotto));
        }

        ClienteModel clienteModel = null;
        clienteModel = new ClienteModel();
        var memoryClienti = dbMemoryManager.ReadAllCliente(clienteModel);
        clientiListBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (ClienteModel model in memoryClienti)
        {
            clientiListBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", clienteModel.Cognome, clienteModel.Nome, clienteModel.Indirizzo));
        }

        ProdottoModel prodottoModel = null;
        prodottoModel = new ProdottoModel();
        var memoryProdotti = dbMemoryManager.ReadAllProdotto(prodottoModel);
        prodottiListBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (ProdottoModel model in memoryProdotti)
        {
            prodottiListBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", prodottoModel.DescrizioneArticolo, prodottoModel.DataProdotto));
        }
    }
```

The ReadAll methods you can see, are all the same, but each one returns one of my three lists so i can get the entire list and use that as i want, this is an example:

```
        public List<CarrelloModel> ReadAllCarrello(CarrelloModel model)
    {
        bool empty = !MemoryCarrello.Any();
        if (empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Carello vuoto");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Testing");
        }
        return MemoryCarrello;
    }
```

When i press the button to return to shop, and try to update lists, those are empty, because the shop can't reach the lists updatet by the console, even if i use ReadAll methods, that shoul be cause of difference istances, what should i do? I'm driving crazy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Shop class and the ConsoleAnagrafica form have two different instances of DBManager. What you put in one of these instance is not in the other one. You need to pass around a single DBManager instance (the first created) and always use the same instance. Another option is to make the DBManager a static class

Comment: Since i'm fairly new to c#, i don't know how to give to different form the same DBManager istance. What should i do?

Comment: Btw i can't make DBManager public since that's an interface, and i can't make DBMemoryManager static too, since i won't be allowed to use my methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shop class and the ConsoleAnagrafica form have two different instances of DBManager. What you put in one of these instances is not in the other one. You need to pass around a single DBMemoryManager instance (the first created) and always use that instance.

So, for example, assuming the ConsoleAnagrafica is the main form of your app and you open the Shop form from this main form you could have

```
public partial class ConsoleAnagrafica : Form
{
    //Istanziazione [0]

    DBMemoryManager dbMemoryManager = null;

    public ConsoleAnagrafica()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dbMemoryManager = new DBMemoryManager();
    }

    // Some click event from button or menu that opens the shop form
    private void OpenShop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Pass the instance in the ConsoleAnagrafica to new Shop instance
        Shop Login = new Shop(dbMemoryManager);
        Login.Show();
    }

}
```

then inside the Shop constructor you receive the instance passed from the console like

```
public partial class Shop : Form
{
    DBMemoryManager dbMemoryManager = null;

    public Shop(DBMemoryManager mgr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dbMemoryManager = mgr;
    }
```

Now the instance inside the Shop form is the same instance created in the Console form. This approach could easily become a nightmare if there are more forms that need to access the same instance of DBMemoryManager.

Comment: Seems like it's working, don't worry about more forms, since that's just practice and learning, so i won't use that in similiar circumnstances. Thank you so much!

Comment: Btw, could you check what' wrong with aggiornaListeButton_Click? event should update listboxes, but i can see cart items, but not customers and products, even if that's the same function and as i can see via debugger, lists are populated.